# Where should certain files be #include'd for these classes?

Tags: c++

I'm making a Radian class and Degree class. Each class has a constructor that takes an object of the other type as an argument, does a degree/radian conversion, and initializes the degree or radian parameter with the result, like so.

```
Class Radian
{
    private:
      double radians;
    public:
      // ......
      Radian(Degree d) {
      radians = d.getDegrees() * (pi / 180);
      }
      // ...
```

And the degree class is the same way but oppposite. So to make sure there isn't some kind of linkage error, should each header #include the other? What about their respective .cpp's? Do I need a forward class declaration?

Comment: @iccthedral He needs both, and also needs to move the implementation of at least one of the class' member functions that refer to the other class into a .cpp file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do three (maybe four) things:

- Use Include Guards - `#ifndef RADIAN_H...`
- Use forward declarations, i.e. `class Degree;`
- Move the constructor body out of the header file and into a .cpp file. This is because a forward declaration of a class won't let you refer to members like `getDegrees()`
- Ideally, make the constructors take `const &` arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You should use forward declaration in this case.

Comment: He can't. The Radian constructor (as written) wouldn't compile.

Comment: I noticed this myself after reading again and flagged the answer already. sorry!

Comment: It's better to fix answer instead of flagging.

Answer (score 0):

Since they're so closely tied together, they probably belong in a single file. That makes writing the two inline constructors possible:

```
class radian;

class degree {
public:
    degree(radian r);
private:
    double degrees;
};


class radian {
public:
    radian(degree d);
private:
    double radians;
};

inline degree::degree(radian r) : degrees(r.get_radians() * 180 / pi) { }
inline radian::radian(degree d) : radians(d.get_degrees() * pi / 180) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would likely do the following:

**forward.hpp**

```
#pragma once
class Radian;
class Degree;
```

**radian.hpp**

```
#pragma once
#include "forward.hpp"

class Radian {
    public:
        Radian(Degree d);

    private:
        double radians;
};
```

**radian.cpp**

```
#include "radian.hpp"
#include "degree.hpp"

Radian::Radian(Degree d) {
    radians = d.getDegrees() * (pi / 180);
}
```

**degree.hpp**

```
#pragma once
#include "forward.hpp"

class Degree {
    public:
        Degree(double x);
        double getDegrees() const;
    private:
        double deg;
}
```

**degree.cpp**

```
#include "degree.hpp"

Degree::Degree(double x) {
    deg = x;
}

double Degree::getDegrees() const {
    return deg;
}
```